# Total Conversion rate each day in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, data-science

Given the following the tables

**User_info:**

- user_id
- Date

**User_trascations:**

- user_id
- Transaction_date
- Purchase_amount

Conversion_rate: out of total users who came on the day, how many users made a transaction on that day.

The table should have

```
------------------------------
 Date    |   converstion_rate
------------------------------
2020-7-9     30%
```

I have tried this but it is returning just one row:

```
select
  date(A.date) as date 
  , count(distinct B.user_id) / 
      count(distinct A.user_id) as conversion
from dau A join rev B
  on A.user_id = B.user_id
group by 1
```

Comment: 7/9/20 is not the same as 20/7/9

Comment: Your question is not clear ... your expected result show one row only  ..  you have one date only but your query comment is  "I have tried this but it is returning just one row:"  ..  you should explain better   your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save dates and time always as proper dates, all else has to be converted.

The followig query only shows rows when there are transactions made, when you wnat also to show the dates , wen there where no transaction you have to switch to LEFT JOIN

> ```
> CREATE TABLE User_info (
>  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
>  Date VARCHAR(255),
>  User_ID VARCHAR(255)
> );
> INSERT INTO User_info
>  (Date,User_ID)
> VALUES
>  ('7/9/2020','1060'),
>  ('7/9/2020','1069'),
>  ('7/9/2020','1089'),
>  ('7/9/2020','1125'),
>  ('7/9/2020','1232'),
>  ('7/9/2020','1264'),
>  ('7/9/2020','1269'),
>  ('7/9/2020','1279'),
>  ('7/9/2020','1292'),
>  ('7/9/2020','2008');
>  
> CREATE TABLE User_trascations(
>  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
>  Date_Time VARCHAR(255),
>  User_ID INT,
>  Revenue FLOAT
> );
> INSERT INTO User_trascations
>  (Date_Time,User_ID,Revenue)
> VALUES
>  ('2020-7-9 9.20.56.281000000 ',1269,13.993),
>  ('2020-7-9 8.16.52.214000000 ',1279,1.393),
>  ('2020-7-9 7.17.49.895000000 ',1232,1.393),
>  ('2020-7-9 6.54.6.846000000 ',1264,1.393),
>  ('2020-7-9 6.46.51.135000000 ',1232,6.993),
>  ('2020-7-9 6.41.32.654000000 ',1125,1.393),
>  ('2020-7-9 5.58.37.464000000 ',1279,6.993),
>  ('2020-7-9 4.35.20.509000000 ',1279,7.2779448),
>  ('2020-7-9 4.19.26.254000000 ',1232,3.493),
>  ('2020-7-9 23.34.20.47000000 ',1232,3.493),
>  ('2020-7-9 22.53.19.828000000 ',1232,6.993),
>  ('2020-7-9 21.38.14.723000000 ',1264,6.993),
>  ('2020-7-9 20.38.50.284000000 ',1264,6.993),
>  ('2020-7-9 20.34.34.235000000 ',1279,6.993),
>  ('2020-7-9 18.57.47.459000000 ',1264,3.493),
>  ('2020-7-9 18.57.2.383000000 ',1279,1.393),
>  ('2020-7-9 18.38.20.297000000 ',1279,1.393),
>  ('2020-7-9 18.29.26.471000000 ',1089,7.214527773),
>  ('2020-7-9 18.27.53.275000000 ',1232,1.393),
>  ('2020-7-9 18.26.6.499000000 ',1264,6.993),
>  ('2020-7-9 18.22.0.159000000 ',1089,1.393),
>  ('2020-7-9 17.0.1.171000000 ',1232,13.993),
>  ('2020-7-9 16.29.3.477000000 ',1232,1.393),
>  ('2020-7-9 15.7.23.893000000 ',1264,3.493),
>  ('2020-7-9 15.51.53.701000000 ',1279,3.486),
>  ('2020-7-9 13.48.47.687000000 ',1264,3.493);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT t1.date_t1, t2.count_t2/t1.count_t1
> FROM (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT User_ID) count_t1 ,STR_TO_DATE(`Date`,'%m/%d/%y') date_t1 FROm User_info GROUP BY STR_TO_DATE(`Date`,'%m/%d/%y')) t1
>  INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT User_ID) count_t2,DATE(`Date_Time`) date_t2 FROm User_trascations GROUP BY DATE(`Date_Time`)) t2
>  ON t1.date_t1 = t2.date_t2
> ```
>
> ```
> date_t1    | t2.count_t2/t1.count_t1
> :--------- | ----------------------:
> 2020-07-09 |                  0.6000
> ```

> ```
> SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT User_ID) count_t1 ,STR_TO_DATE(`Date`,'%m/%d/%y') date_t1 FROm User_info GROUP BY STR_TO_DATE(`Date`,'%m/%d/%y')
> ```
>
> ```
> count_t1 | date_t1   
> -------: | :---------
>       10 | 2020-07-09
> ```

> ```
> SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT User_ID) count_t2,DATE(`Date_Time`) date_t2 FROm User_trascations GROUP BY DATE(`Date_Time`)
> ```
>
> ```
> count_t2 | date_t2   
> -------: | :---------
>        6 | 2020-07-09
> ```

> ```
>   SELECT STR_TO_DATE(`Date`,'%m/%d/%y') FROM User_info;
> ```
>
> ```
> | STR_TO_DATE(`Date`,'%m/%d/%y') |
> | :----------------------------- |
> | 2020-07-09                     |
> | 2020-07-09                     |
> | 2020-07-09                     |
> | 2020-07-09                     |
> | 2020-07-09                     |
> | 2020-07-09                     |
> | 2020-07-09                     |
> | 2020-07-09                     |
> | 2020-07-09                     |
> | 2020-07-09                     |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b438a79dd3e95a35c0887649947873b7)*

By month ansd year

```
SELECT 
    t1.date_t1 AS Date,
    total_users_on_a_day,
    Users_who_made_pruchase
FROM
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT User_ID) total_users_on_a_day,
            DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%m/%d/%y'),'%Y-%m') date_t1
    FROM
        User_info
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%m/%d/%y'),'%Y-%m')) t1
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT User_ID) Users_who_made_pruchase,
            DATE_FORMAT(Date_Time,'%Y-%m') date_t2
    FROM
        User_trascations
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(Date_Time,'%Y-%m') WITH ROLLUP) t2 ON t1.date_t1 = t2.date_t2
```

Comment: 2How do I get an over all conversation rate for this month? I have made slight changes to the same query I am confused where to include the roll up so that I get a total at the end of the column

Comment: SELECT t1.date_t1 AS Date, 
total_users_on_a_day,
Users_who_made_pruchase
FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT User_ID) total_users_on_a_day,
STR_TO_DATE(`Date`,'%m/%d/%y') date_t1 
FROM daily_active_users
GROUP BY STR_TO_DATE(`Date`,'%m/%d/%y')) t1
 INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT User_ID) Users_who_made_pruchase,
 DATE(`Date_Time`) date_t2 
 FROM rev 
 GROUP BY DATE(`Date_Time`)with rollup) t2
 ON t1.date_t1 = t2.date_t2

Comment: please see changed answer